# Web hosting - horizontal scaling

Tags: routing, virtualhost

I have a single machine that I use to host multiple websites with virtual hosts (lighttpd webserver), I can't say I am in a professional environment as I am hosting mainly for small websites and projects.

Eventually, the resources of a single machine will not be enough to cover the requests amount and I will need to add another one to my network.

What is a common technique to route the requests to the right server? It is a really simple structure, visually imagine it like this:

```
SERVER X
  website A (vhost)
  website B (vhost)
  website C (vhost)
SERVER Y
  website D (vhost)
  website E (vhost)
  website n (vhost)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you never need to have a single site running on more than one server at a time, there's nothing stopping you from pointing the DNS entries for the sites in question at the correct server's IP address.

If you *did* need to have a single site running on more than one server at a time, then you'd probably want to consider either a load balancer or setting up your DNS as a Round-Robin. The former is definitely preferred - but worry about that when you need it, if you need it.

Comment: The thing is that all the servers in the network resolve to only one external address, forgot to mention that in the question.

Comment: @johnsmith You'll have to get more IP addresses, then.